# JNDI name format of JMS queue in wildfly10

Tags: jms, wildfly, wildfly-10, jms-queue

Hi I am migrating to wildfly 10 from JBoss_6.1.0_final.

In JBoss for Queue name the format is like

```
<queue name="TEST_QUEUE">
  <entry name="/queue/TEST_QUEUE"/>
</queue>
```

and in MDB annotation is

```
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination",
                propertyValue = "queue/TEST_QUEUE")
```

Now in wildfly its like below. [reference link](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Messaging+configuration)

```
<jms-queue name="TEST_QUEUE" entries="jms/queue/TEST_QUEUE java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/TEST_QUEUE"/>
```

with activationproperty

```
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination",
                        propertyValue = "jms/queue/TEST_QUEUE")
```

In wildfly I have tried by removing the `jms/` from queue name and from annotation, its working fine in wildfly with same queue name , 
like

```
<jms-queue name="TEST_QUEUE" entries="queue/TEST_QUEUE java:jboss/exported/queue/TEST_QUEUE"/>
```

Now my question is, Is `JMS/` in queue name added purposefully.

it is good practice to write queue name without prefix `jms/`

Answer (score 2):

From the JEE JSR part **EE.5.7.1.2 Programming Interfaces for Resource Manager Connection Factory References**

> This specification recommends, but does not require, that all resource manager connection factory references be organized in the subcontexts of the application component’s environment, using a different subcontext for each resource manager type. For example, all JDBC™ DataSource references should be declared in the java:comp/env/jdbc subcontext, all JMS connection factories in the java:comp/env/jms subcontext, all JavaMail connection factories in the java:comp/env/mail subcontext, and all URL connection factories in the java:comp/env/url subcontext. Note that resource manager connection factory references declared via annotations will not, by default, appear in any subcontext

the `jms` subcontext is not mandatory. It is just a best practice.

Servers can or not follow this pattern. JBoss was not following this, wildfly is, but ultimately, it is YOUR decision to do what you want. But this is a really good practice to follow as it is cleaner for everybody.